# Loop list to run ansible task

Tags: loops, ansible

I have a task wrote by someone else. It was aimed for a single use with a single variable. I would like to avoid rewriting it with a list instead of a simple variable.

Then I would like to set a list for each host in host_vars:

```yaml
list:
  - value_1
  - ...
  - value_n
```

and in a playbook, reuse the task for each value:

```
 loop the list, and for each value:
   reset the main variable used in task with the value_n
   run the task
```

Is it possible?
That's so basic in shell but seems so complicated with Ansible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK -- I know you're new at this, but you should post code of what you have tried, and post the errors you're getting.  Anyway, here's a simple loop example run on `localhost` (you may need to use a different host, if `localhost` is not in your inventory):

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    list:
    - value_1
    - value_2
    - value_n

  tasks:
  - name: Loop with default variable (item)
    debug:
      msg: "item is {{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ list }}"
   
  - name: Loop with named variable (main_variable)
    debug:
      msg: "main_variable is {{ main_variable }}"
    loop: "{{ list }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: main_variable
```

And here are the results from `ansible-playbook ./simple_loop.yml`:

```
$ ansible-playbook ./simple_loop.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************

TASK [Loop with default variable (item)] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=value_1) => {
    "msg": "item is value_1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=value_2) => {
    "msg": "item is value_2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=value_n) => {
    "msg": "item is value_n"
}

TASK [Loop with named variable (main_variable)] ************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=value_1) => {
    "msg": "main_variable is value_1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=value_2) => {
    "msg": "main_variable is value_2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=value_n) => {
    "msg": "main_variable is value_n"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Sorry, I have not been trained in this uncommon language. The only loop I knew was "with_items" to perform 1 single action and I had no idea how to include a variable assignment in loop, that's why I used words to describe my need, not code.

Comment: No worries.  The `with_items` construct is older, and what I started with, too.  But I'm working to use `loop` instead, because it's more flexible.